# Test API, Dynamic Threads

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests, soapui, locust

I want test an API.

**My scenario:**

- 1 hour.
- From 0 to 300, 000 users.
- 3 request by user.
- Users (threads)
  increments by second, like +5, +15, +20, +5, +30.
- threads are remove also, -2, -5, -15, -5.
- When the threads is alive, call again the 3 requests every 20 seconds for example.

You know some aplications for this or a better for to simulate this, i mada a little tests with JMeter, SoapUI, and Locust IO but it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can more or less easily implement it with JMeter, the relevant test elements would be:

1. [Ultimate Thread Group](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420305-How-To-Configure-Ultimate-Stepping-Thread-Groups-Scenario) to mimic your weird threads ramp-up and ramp-down pattern. This is not a part of standard JMeter shipment, you will need to install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
2. [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) - to limit hits per second to the desired amount of requests per second
3. Given `300 000` virtual users requirement - most probably you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)